# Remove Device without Factory Reset/Removing Data?

Tags: .net, mdm, android-management-api

I've setup an enterprise, policy, and have provisioned my device. However, if this device is removed from the enterprise, the device is factory reset.

Is it possible to skip the factory reset step? I am using AMA mostly to batch install apps and adjust a few settings, so a factory reset would wipe all of this data that I want to keep on the device.

If not, is there an alternative to batch installing apps? Is using AMA overkill for my use case?

I found this flag in the Remove command, but turns out it just ignores the command instead of telling it to "skip factory reset"

```
        var request = androidManagementService.Enterprises.Devices.Delete(device.Name);
        request.WipeDataFlags = EnterprisesResource.DevicesResource.DeleteRequest.WipeDataFlagsEnum.WIPEDATAFLAGUNSPECIFIED;
        var result = request.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

No APIs are available in AMAPI that will enable users/admins to skip factory reset when the device is removed from the enterprise, as this is the intended behavior.

When an admin removes an Android device from the associated enterprise, all work data and apps associated with the account are removed from the device. If the device has a work profile, then work-managed apps are removed from the device, too. Your Google Workspace data is still available when you sign in with your computer, a web browser, or another authorized mobile device. If you don't have a work profile or the legacy Device Administrator mode and you remove your work account, when you add it back to your device, all apps on your device are removed, including any personal apps.

[WipeDataFlag](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22enterprises%2FLC03oveayg%2Fdevices%2F31d01a4e7e2b8650%22%2C%22wipeDataFlags%22%3A%5B%22WIPE_DATA_FLAG_UNSPECIFIED%22%5D%2C%22wipeReasonMessage%22%3A%22Testing%20Coffee%22%7D#wipedataflag) can control the data-wiping behavior when a device is deleted (to some extent), **but it will not be able to skip the factory reset entirely.**

The PRESERVE_RESET_PROTECTION_DATA flag tells the Android Management API to preserve the factory reset protection data on the device. This means that the device will still be locked and require the user to enter their Google account password to unlock it, even after it has been reset. This flag is useful if you want to ensure that the device is not reset without your permission. It can also be used to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the device's data.

To use this flag, you must include it in the WipeDataFlag parameter of the enterprises.devices.delete method. For example:

```
enterprises.devices.delete(deviceId, null, null, WipeDataFlag.FLAG_WIPE_ALL_DATA | WipeDataFlag.PRESERVE_RESET_PROTECTION_DATA);
```

Batch installing apps is a valid use-case for Android Management API. "is this overkill?" would depend a bit on your specific use case. Still, we don't have enough info on what your individual use case is to be able to provide additional context.

Comment: I found that you can issue a command, and it lists `RELINQUISH_OWNERSHIP` as a potential command. Does this command work?

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand#CommandType